# Menu Highlight , javascript(jquery) isnt including title section top padding

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code and i it isnt recognising my h1 padding from the top of the section, so the highlight only works when the page position is on top of that h1 , not when the section starts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('nav a').each(function () {
        var currentLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.outerHeight( true ) > scrollPosition) {
            $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currentLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currentLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

I have also a menu animation in which the menu resizes on scroll,

but heres my html

```
   <section class="ui masthead segment" id="A ID" >
    <div class="ui page grid">
      <div class="column">
       <img src="images/logo.png" class="ui medium image">
        <div class="ui hidden transition information">
          <h1 class="ui blue header">
            A h1
          </h1>
          <p>blablabla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: There is no question without a sample of what you have so far... add your HTML or a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ to help describe your question better.

Comment: Oh sorry , i edited ...